# How can I make sure my PHP session variables are there when I need them?

Tags: php, session-variables

I am working on a page that has 3 sections. In the first section, one of the inputs is a number that is required by the second section. In the second section, one of the inputs is a number that is required by the third section. When the users submits the form in the first section, I store that number in a session variable, when the user submits the form in the second section, I store that number in a session variable as well. Each time a section is submitted, the next section, with its associated form, will become "visible".

```
+-----------+
|  My Page  |
+-----------+
| section 1 | -> set section 1 variable needed by section 2 and 3
+-----------+
| section 2 | -> set section 2 variable needed by section 3
+-----------+
| section 3 |
+-----------+
```

My question is, how do I make sure my session variables are still there when I go to store the form data in the database? Say a person submits section 1, then section 2, then goes away for a long while, comes back, and tries to submit section 3. Or, a user submits section 1, then goes away for a long while, comes back, and tries to submit section 2. How do I make sure the session data is still there before attempting a database CRUD? I though about retrieving the session variables with each new section and adding them as hidden fields in the next sections form, but I wasn't sure if this was a good idea or not.

Anyway, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read, and have a great day. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check their existence like so:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['varName')) { // do something }
```

Comment: I thought about that. But what if, in that brief span of time when I check, the session variable gets unset? I know it is highly unlikely, but what if?

Comment: Always check when someone tries to progress to the next page. Don't let progression happen without being sure all vars are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use flags (flags is is a idea not tecnology or comand)

```
//first part of code:

if (!isset($_SESSION['firstpart']))
{
     $_SESSION['firstpart'] = false;
     $_SESSION['secondpart'] = false;
     $_SESSION['thirdpart'] = false; 
}


//(and then)
if($_SESSION['firstpart'] == false)
{
   validate first part variables
   do someting to read or say give me first part

   if vars is ok
        $_SESSION['firstpart'] = true;
   else
       $_SESSION['firstpart'] = false;
}

 //validting second part
if($_SESSION['secondpart'] == false)
{
    we can validate an do second part

    and set:
    if vars is ok
        $_SESSION['secondpart'] = true;
   else
       $_SESSION['secondpart'] = false;

}

// and repeat for third part
```

and all vars in sessions, first stablish flags on false and then activate each part for know where is user.